I don't think it's serving me right
On TV, some people are discussing about how students might change their minds about the department they chose in the beginning of uviversity. A man said about his daughter's case:
Dad I'm just not enjoying it here, and I don't think it's serving me right. I want to come back and get and get a job. I said, well then, do it and so she left and it was the best thing she ever did. ITV - Is university worth debt (see:9:05-9:25)
I looked "serve someone right" up, and found this in Cambridge:
"If you say that something bad serves someone right, you mean that that person deserves it."
So, does the student mean she didn't simply like the department in terms the subjects, or does she think the level is too low, she is more clever, more intelligent, much better than the others in her department, which is why she might have considered the department a bad thing that happened to her.

It serves you right. is accurate as the Cambridge Dictionary says,  for something bad.  This is not that. The choice of study is not the one she thinks is best for her. That does not mean it's "bad.

[bad outcome] serves you right! is a gloatingly ironic "frozen form" idiomatic usage. Your cited example is just normal use of the words with their overt literal meanings. I don't think it's serving me right = I think I'm not getting what I need / expect / deserve from it.

The sentence you quote would have been more clear (and less ambiguous) if it had been expressed as “I don’t think it’s serving me well.”

The phrase is too vague to know exactly what she meant.  She feels the school is just not right for her.

I think you are right that it sounds like an unusual expression (at least to me).Yet, the meaning is clear: "serving me well". "Working out in my favor."

This usage is not the same as the definition you looked up. It's also fairly unusual.
When she says it's not serving her right, what she means is that it's not providing her with what she needs right now; it's not meeting or fulfilling her needs. She is getting some benefit -- it's just not the right benefit.
You might hear people more commonly say that something doesn't serve their needs or serve their purpose. It means it's not giving them what they need or expect.
